# Stop nivo slider effect when some conditions occurs

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I don't want to slide nivo slider when the last image is focused.Example

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    manualAdvance: true,
    beforeChange: function(){
        if(condition){
           //do not go to afterChange function
        }
    },
    afterChange: function(){

    }, 
});
```

Can i stop the slider from sliding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NivoSlides has two functions to start/stop the slider, as [noted in its documentation.](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation)

$('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop(); //Stop the Slider
$('#slider').data('nivoslider').start(); //Start the Slider

So you can try this:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
        manualAdvance: true,
        beforeChange: function(){
            if(condition){
               $('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
            }
        },
        afterChange: function(){

        }, 
    });
```